# Message Templates Font Color Change

Tags: message-templates

Message Templates I want to specify the color of the text "Status - Send Copy of an Activity" for incoming mail as color code 1f497d.

So I want to replace the posts in the table with 1f497d color, not black. How can I do that.

[image]

Comment: Note the screenshot image seems unavailable.

Comment: Hi  @demerit, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the message template there's two lines near the top that look like this:

```
{capture assign=labelStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; background-color: #f7f7f7;"{/capture}
{capture assign=valueStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999;"{/capture}
```

If you change them to add a `color: #1f497d;` to look like this it should work:

```
{capture assign=labelStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; background-color: #f7f7f7; color: #1f497d;"{/capture}
{capture assign=valueStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; color: #1f497d;"{/capture}
```

Comment: Super thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to ask you one more thing.
When more content (words, etc.) is entered in the Details section, the side headers field starts to narrow. So column 1 is almost narrow enough to fall into one word and it looks very ugly in this mail. Is it possible to ensure that there is no such contraction in the table structure?

[image]

Comment: You can try something like adding `min-width: 20em;` to the line that has `labelStyle`.

Comment: Yes, that was a great solution to my problem.